# Blazor : embed shows pdf correctly in Firefox, but empty in Chrome and Edge

Tags: pdf, base64, blazor, embed

I'm using "embed" to show pdf file in Razor component of Blazor Server

```
<embed src="@showedPdfContent" visible="false" width="1100" height="730" type="application/pdf"/>

public void SetPdfContent(byte[] content)
{
    showedPdfContent = $"data:application/pdf;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(content)}";
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

when I run with Firefox, it works correctly to show pdf file. But, when I run with Chrome or Edge, it shows empty.

[embed in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTOxI.png)

I tried to use "object" or "iframe". But they also didn't work as well. Any ideas to this issue?

Comment: I tried to wrap with iframe:  `<iframe src="@showedPdfContent" type="application/pdf" width="750px" height="750px">
                <embed src="@showedPdfContent" visible="false" width="1100" height="730" type="application/pdf"/>
           </iframe>` . But it still didn't work.

Comment: I tried to write byte array to the temporary pdf file, view file by Embed and it works. I don't know why it doesn't work with base64: Convert.ToBase64String(content)

Comment: I tried to browse with Fiddle and my pdf base64 content https://jsfiddle.net/fhd30bko/ . and it works. I don't know why it doesn't work for Google Chrome / Edge.

Comment: I don't think that it related with Blazor. But, when I open https://jsfiddle.net/fhd30bko/ with Firefox, it works correctly. But, with Chrome, it shows blank for pdf content.

Comment: Hi @Quang Vinh Tran, just wondering if you got this to work in Chrome ? having the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

A `iframe`, `object`or `embed` didn't worked for me in chrome.

As a workaround u can use the `Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime`. Convert the pdf to a base64 string and load it with [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/).

[A example](https://github.com/benjamin-t-wilson/BlazorPDFViewer)